# In gawk gensub prints only one backslash

Tags: awk, gawk

Here under, I expected two back slashes, but get one,

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/\[/,"\\\\","g")}1' <(echo [)
\
```

`sub` works okay.

Thanks,

Eric J.

Comment: Try 8 slashes - bash likely escapes the 4 slashes to 2, and then awk will escape them again, resulting in a single slash.

Comment: @Njol. No, bash (or other OS/shell) has nothing to do with this. See HakonHaegland's answer - escapes in string literals are parsed twice by awk, once when awk reads the script and again when awk executes the script and the rules for (g)sub() handling backslashes are different from those for gensub() due to history/POSIX/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is explained here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Gory-Details

From that link it can be seen that the there is a difference in behavior depending upon

- which version of `awk` you are using, and
- if you use `gensub()` or `sub()`